# Partition APFS for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac

I want to partition my macOS SSD so I can dual boot into Ubuntu. I am running the latest version of Mojave and utilizing APFS.

I created two more partitions on the SSD, for a total of three: the Mac partition, a partition for Ubuntu as MS-DOS(FAT), and a dedicated swap partition also formatted as MS-DOS(FAT).  Every single time I try to do this the process fails to complete. I have been able to get the Ubuntu partition to go but nothing past that one time.

In the guide I was using it mentioned that with APFS you can have issues partitioning the hard drive. If that is the case it is recommended to erase your hard drive and format it to journal extended. I really don't want to do this because I am using a 2014 Mac Mini. With the addition of an SSD and APFS it runs like it is brand new.

Is there a way around this where I don't have to go back to journaled extended?

Can I go back to journal extended, repartition the SSD then reinstall Ubuntu; then reformat only the Mac portion of the SSD back to APFS?

Comment: FAT is not the normal partition type for Linux. Ubuntu defaults to ext4, and with the current LTS release, 18.04, it defaults to no swap partition, instead using a swap file instead. Suggest you use 18.04 LTS, and just add one partition for Linux which is ext4.

Answer (score 1):

So right after posting this I did the partitions one at a time instead of in a group and it worked with out any issues. I guess the issue is trying to execute multiple partitions in the process, doesn't work all that well.

Comment: New installations of 18.04 do not require a swap partition anymore by default. They make only one partition for everything and a swap file instead of a swap partition.